# XCode 15 no such module '__ObjC'

Tags: flutter, xcode15

[image: here is screenshot of the problem]

when i run pod install these wornings comes.

`[!] The` Runner [Debug]`target overrides the`ENABLE_BITCODE`build setting defined in`Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Release]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)` flag, or
- Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `Runner [Profile]` target overrides the `ENABLE_BITCODE` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the` $(inherited)`flag, or - Remove the build settings from the target.`
after that when i debug on real device Xcode through an error no such module '__ObjC'.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share the log for the two commands: `flutter doctor -v` and `pod --version`? I want to make sure that every configuration is right to execute.